# Bokeh Categorical Data Heatmap Not Showing

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to create a Heatmap from a csv using python pandas.  I keep on getting a blank screen for my output, and I not sure why-- I've exhausted the documentation online to try to figure it out.  My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import (
    ColumnDataSource,
    HoverTool,
    LinearColorMapper,
    BasicTicker,
    PrintfTickFormatter,
    ColorBar,
    FactorRange
)
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.unemployment1948 import data
from bokeh.transform import transform

#Initialize DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv("myData.csv") 

df.dropna().astype(float)
df.columns.name = 'Month'
df.index.name = 'Facility'

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(df.stack(), columns=['state']).reset_index()
source = ColumnDataSource(df_1)  


#Heatmap
colors = ["#75968f", "#a5bab7", "#c9d9d3", "#e2e2e2", "#dfccce", "#ddb7b1", "#cc7878", "#933b41", "#550b1d"]
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=colors, low=df_1.state.min(), high=df_1.state.max())

TOOLS = "hover,save,pan,box_zoom,reset,wheel_zoom"

p = figure(title="WSSDM4",
           x_range= list(df.columns), y_range=list(df.index),
           x_axis_location="above", plot_width=1800, plot_height=800,
           tools= TOOLS, toolbar_location='below',
           tooltips=[('Facility', '@Facility'), ('Month', '@Month')])

p.rect(x='Facility', y = 'Month',width=1, height=1, source=source,
        line_color=None, fill_color=transform('state', mapper))
   
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=mapper, major_label_text_font_size="7px",
                     ticker=BasicTicker(desired_num_ticks=len(colors)),
                     label_standoff=6, border_line_color=None, location=(0, 0))

p.add_layout(color_bar, 'right')

p.axis.axis_line_color = None
p.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
p.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "7px"
p.axis.major_label_standoff = 0
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.0
show(p)
```

I am using Jupyter notebooks and have all the up-to-date libraries.

Thank you!

Comment: 1) the code as written isn't runnable, because it depends on myData.csv, so it's difficult to test; any way to update so that it's runnable as-is?
2) often more info can be found in the browser's javascript web console when bokeh hits errors-- anything of interest there?

Comment: Hi! I should have added-- it works when I use data already provided (just change the column names), but doesn't work on my data even though I made sure the data types and structure were the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is this line:
`df.index.name = 'Facility'`

All this would do is name the existing df index (which looks like 0, 1, 2, 3...) "Facility," rather than taking the existing `Facility` column and making it the index. To do that, you'd want:
`df = df.set_index('Facility')`

I found this discrepancy by adding a bunch of `print(df.head())` statements after each line where your code modified the dataset, and doing the same in the original Bokeh heatmap example, and looking for where they diverged. Might be useful in case there are other problems.

Comment: Thank you for the response! So I did that, and it's all the correct indices, columns, data types, etc.  Is there something I am missing regarding the source = ColumnDataSource(df_1)  ? I think the issue is in there, but at this point I'm clueless.

Comment: That part seems okay; I see you've brought the question over to the Bokeh Discourse, so hopefully when we get a sample of your data we can further diagnose.